# Task %Complete calculated column show date/time

Tags: validation

Im trying to create a calculated column to show completion date of a task based on %complete.

So if the task has hit 100% then it should autofill a date/time value based on this percentage.

Answer (score 1):

A calculated column wont work they way you want it to.
I would recommend to rather create a workflow which on save:

```
If %complete = 100% {
   If date/time-column = empty {
      Set date/time-column to Changed (time/date)
   }
}
```